# failed to load resource hexo.js

Tags: html, css, node.js, hexo

**I'm using HexoJS to create a blog.** I was able to generate the static files using `hexo generate`. Even though there are css files and JS files generated, they are not properly linked to the `index.html`.

**So, I have to open each html page and correct each page links given in href and src attributes one by one.** I believe that this is not very practical. Can anyone help ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localhost is used for preview the website. When we publish our blog, it should be on a server, then the path will be interpreted correctly, we don't need to change any thing. What we saw on http://localhost:4000 will be same when you published your website.

So, we don't have to worry about the broken paths in the public folder.